# Datepicker style for Expression dark theme

Tags: wpf, datepicker, styling

I'm using the expression dark theme for one of my WPF apps, I've tried to style it to work with the theme but I'm just to damn bad at WPF styling to get it to work, do you guys now if someone have styled the Datepicker to match Expression dark?

http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question is YES.

I am just pulling your nose. DatePicker is really complicated one. Best you can do is utilize Expression Blend to get default template and work with that. Of course ControlTemplate for DatePicker is not enough... but I am sure you already know that.

You have to edit templates for all parts of Datepicker and all parts of Calendar

So if you use Expression Blend to play with those default styles... you will end up with styles for

Datepicker, Button(part of DatePicker), DatePickerTextBox, Calendar, CalendarItem, CalendarButton, CalendarDayButton.

You can edit them one by one.

I would really be happy to post code here, but it has over 500 lines. And I am sure that now - when you really know what you want to edit - you can do it yourself. You don't want to copy-paste it :)